# Ceiling function on TI-84 Plus

Tags: real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, calculator

I am the owner of a TI-84 Plus CE-T and recently I was trying to solve a problem in which a ceiling function was required. I could not find an option to do this in the mats menu, or any of the other menus and I was wondering if this function is present at all on this calculator.

I did manage to find a floor function masked as `int(x)` and therefore was wondering if it has some alternate name that I am not accustomed to.

If no such function exists, how would one go about implementing one?

Comment: Well, it's basically the floor plus $1$, with the (notable) exception that, for integers $n$. the floor equals the ceiling (equals $n$).  Alternatively, $\lceil x\rceil =-\lfloor -x\rfloor$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, that last part was the solution to my problem, now I can just do `-int(-x)`